# Why make_move_iterator() cannot work with back_inserter()?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, c++17

I'm trying to compile simple piece of code under C++17 standard:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> numbers = {6, 1, 3, 9, 1, 9, 8, 12, 1};
    vector<int> res;

    copy(begin(numbers), end(numbers), make_move_iterator(back_inserter(res)));

    return 0;
}
```

I get an error on `make_move_iterator(back_inserter(res))`.

Beginning of error is (excluding senseless (in my opinion) subsequent information):

```
In file included from C:/Users/Name/mingw/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from C:/Users/Name/mingw/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/algorithm:61,
                 from C:\Users\Name\CLionProjects\coursera_cpp_course3\week5\c3_w5_t6_merge_sort_3\c3_w5_t6_merge_sort_3.cpp:2:
C:/Users/Name/mingw/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h: In instantiation of 'class std::move_iterator<std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int> > >':
C:\Users\Name\CLionProjects\coursera_cpp_course3\week5\c3_w5_t6_merge_sort_3\c3_w5_t6_merge_sort_3.cpp:49:77:   required from here
C:/Users/Name/mingw/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:1023:24: error: forming reference to void
     __base_ref>::type  reference;
                        ^~~~~~~~~
```

I've read [documentation on make_move_iterator()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator), and haven't seen any preconditions on use of it here.

Why does it happen? Thank you for your suggestions.

Conditions under which I try to compile:

- Windows 10
- MinGW 8.1.0
- CMake 3.17.1

**Update:** I understood my fault. Here should be:

```cpp
copy(make_move_iterator(begin(numbers)), make_move_iterator(end(numbers)), back_inserter(res));
```

Comment: Your update should have been posted as an answer instead.  You can [answer your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document you linked to clearly says:

> Parameters
>
> i     -   **input iterator** to be converted to move iterator

`std::back_insert_iterator` is not an **input iterator**, it is an **output iterator**.  The `value_type` of `std::back_insert_iterator` is `void`, which is what the error message is complaining about:

> forming reference to void

Comment: Is it just me, or is it weird that he/she is using `std::copy` with `std::make_move_iterator`. Isn't that less efficient than just passing the `move_iterator`'s to the `ctor` of `res`?

Comment: The end effect is the same. You will have to profile the two codes to see which is really more efficient.

Comment: @WBuck the actual code is more difficult. There was the minimal example of issue I faced in given example.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::make_move_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator) contructs an [`std::move_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator), which is suppoed to work with an *InputIterator*, i.e. to move the values from the iterator instead of copying them.

> `std::move_iterator` is an iterator adaptor which behaves exactly like the underlying iterator (**which must be at least an [*LegacyInputIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator)**), except that dereferencing converts the value returned by the underlying iterator into an rvalue. **If this iterator is used as an input iterator, the effect is that the values are moved from, rather than copied from**.